# Induction proof for $ \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ n \frac 1 { i \cdot ( i + 1 ) } = 1 - \frac 1 { n + 1 } $

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Prove that for any positive integer $ n $ applies:
> $$ \frac 1 { 1 \cdot 2 } + \frac 1 { 2 \cdot 3 } + \frac 1 { 3 \cdot 4 } + \dots + \frac 1 { n \cdot ( n + 1 ) } = \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ n \frac 1 { i \cdot ( i + 1 ) } = 1 - \frac 1 { n + 1 } \text . $$

I have done this so far:

It applies for $ n = 1 $ because $ 1 - \frac 1 { n + 1 } = 1 - \frac 1 { 1 + 1 } = 1 - \frac 1 2 = \frac 1 2 $ but what about $ n = j + 1 $:
$$ \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ j \frac 1 { i \cdot ( i + 1 ) } = 1 - \frac 1 { j + 1 } $$
I have substituted $ j $ for $ n $ and now consider the expression for $ j + 1 $, $ \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ { j + 1 } \frac 1 { i \cdot ( i + 1 ) } $:
\begin{align*}
\sum _ { i = 1 } ^ { j + 1 } \frac 1 { i \cdot ( i + 1 ) }
& = \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ j \frac 1 { i \cdot ( i + 1 ) } + \frac 1 { ( j + 1 ) \cdot \bigl ( ( j + 1 ) + 1 \bigr ) } \\
& = 1 - \frac 1 { j + 1 } + \frac 1 { ( j + 1 ) \cdot \bigl ( ( j + 1 ) + 1 \bigr ) } \\
& = 1 - \frac 1 { j + 1 } + \frac 1 { ( j + 1 ) \cdot ( j + 2 ) } \\
& = 1 - \frac { 1 \cdot \bigl ( ( j + 1 ) \cdot ( j + 2 ) \bigr ) } { ( j + 1 ) \cdot \bigl ( ( j + 1 ) \cdot ( j + 2 ) \bigr ) } + \frac { 1 \cdot ( j + 1 ) } { ( j + 1 ) \cdot \bigl ( ( j + 1 ) \cdot ( j + 2 ) \bigr ) } \\
& = 1 - \frac { ( j + 1 ) \cdot ( j + 2 ) + j + 1 } { ( j + 1 ) \cdot \bigl ( ( j + 1 ) \cdot ( j + 2 ) \bigr ) } \\
& = 1 - \frac { ( j + 1 ) \cdot ( j + 2 ) + j + 1 } { ( j + 1 ) ^ 2 \cdot ( j + 2 ) } \\
& = 1 - \frac { j + 1 } { ( j + 1 ) ^ 2 } \cdot \left ( \frac { j + 2 } { j + 1 } + \frac { j + 1 } { j + 2 } \right ) \\
& = 1 - \frac 1 { j + 1 } \cdot \left ( 1 + \frac { j + 1 } { j + 2 } \right ) \\
& = 1 - \frac 1 { j + 1 } + \frac 1 { j + 1 } \cdot \frac { j + 1 } { j + 2 } \\
& = 1 - \left ( \frac 1 { j + 1 } + \frac { j + 1 } { ( j + 1 ) \cdot ( j + 2 ) } \right ) \\
& = 1 - \frac 1 { j + 1 } + \frac 1 { j + 2 }
\end{align*}

Comment: Please type your question and don't replace maths expressions by these images, to be accessible by screen readers.

Comment: The wrong step was when you combine these two fractions:

$$\cdots-\frac{1\cdot ((j+1)\cdot(j+2))}{(j+1)\cdot((j+1)\cdot(j+2))} + \frac{1\cdot (j+1)}{(j+1)\cdot((j+1)\cdot(j+2))}$$

Comment: Another wrong step is when you try to rewrite
$$ \frac { ( j + 1 ) \cdot ( j + 2 ) + j + 1 } { ( j + 1 ) ^ 2 \cdot ( j + 2 ) } $$
as
$$ \frac { j + 1 } { ( j + 1 ) ^ 2 } \cdot \left ( \frac { j + 2 } { j + 1 } + \frac { j + 1 } { j + 2 } \right ) \text . $$

Comment: Another nother wrong step is when I just rewrite in blind, I assume I want to get back to the initial assumption in order to prove the prove ? :)

Comment: So @peterwhy do I even need to combine the fractions or should I just factorise instead or what do I need to do ? :)

Comment: @TimmRasmussen More hints: 1. (from my comment) note the $-$ and $+$ signs; 2. (from Mohsen's comment) double check your factorisation step.

Comment: I forgot the - minus sign!